# How do I setup a RSS subscribe page in Django Zinnia?

Tags: django, rss, zinnia

I set up my blog using Django Zinnia. Zinnia includes a RSS feed module by default. I can access the feeds page by the URL **mywebsite.com/blog/feeds**. Right now the page is just the XML for a RSS feed. I am looking to make a page more like this: http://www.cnn.com/services/rss/. How would I get the URLs I need to copy to a feed reader? What about the Yahoo RSS reader buttons? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feed URLs in Zinnia are visible here: [urls/feeds.py](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/blob/master/zinnia/urls/feeds.py).

To get the URL of the main feed this should do: `{% url 'zinnia_entry_latest_feed' %}`.

Comment: In `feeds.py`, I see: `url(r'^$',
        LatestEntries(),
        name='zinnia_entry_latest_feed')`. When I go to that URL (`mywebsite.com/blog/feeds`), it's all XML.

Comment: If you want something similar to the CNN page you'll need to create a new view for it as zinnia doesn't provide it out of the box. That view's template will include the `url` tag I mentioned in the answer.